# Multiplying large matrices is much slower with contiguous memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, multidimensional-array, malloc, matrix-multiplication

While implementing a neural network, I noticed that if I allocate memory as a single contiguous block for the data set arrays, execution time increases several times.

Compare these two methods of memory allocation:

```
float** alloc_2d_float(int rows, int cols, int contiguous)
{
    int i;
    float** array = malloc(rows * sizeof(float*));

    if(contiguous)
    {
        float* data = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(float));
        assert(data && "Can't allocate contiguous memory");

        for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
            array[i] = &(data[cols * i]);
    }
    else
        for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            array[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
            assert(array[i] && "Can't allocate memory");
        }

    return array;
}
```

Here are the results when compiling with `-march=native -Ofast` (tried gcc and clang):

```
michael@Pascal:~/NN$ time ./test 300 1 0

Multiplying (100000, 1000) and (300, 1000) arrays 1 times, noncontiguous memory allocation.

Allocating memory:    0.2 seconds
Initializing arrays: 0.8 seconds
Dot product:         3.3 seconds

real    0m4.296s
user    0m4.108s
sys     0m0.188s

michael@Pascal:~/NN$ time ./test 300 1 1

Multiplying (100000, 1000) and (300, 1000) arrays 1 times, contiguous memory allocation.

Allocating memory:    0.0 seconds
Initializing arrays: 40.3 seconds
Dot product:         13.5 seconds    

real    0m53.817s
user    0m4.204s
sys     0m49.664s
```

Here's the code:
https://github.com/michaelklachko/NN/blob/master/test.c

Note that both initializing and dot product are much slower for contiguous memory.

I expected the opposite - a contiguous block of memory should be more cache friendly than a large number of separate small blocks. Or at least they should be similar in performance (this machine has 64GB of RAM, and 90% of it is unused).

EDIT: Here's the compressed self-contained code (I still recommend using the github version instead, which has measuring and formatting statements):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

float** alloc_2d_float(int rows, int cols, int contiguous){
    int i;
    float** array = malloc(rows * sizeof(float*));
    if(contiguous){
        float* data = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(float));
        for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
            array[i] = &(data[cols * i]);
    }
    else
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    return array;
}

void initialize(float** array, int dim1, int dim2){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
        for(j=0; j<dim2; j++)
            array[i][j] = rand()/RAND_MAX;
}

int main(){
    int i,j,k, dim1=100000, dim2=1000, dim3=300;
    int contiguous=0;
    float temp;

    float** array1 = alloc_2d_float(dim1, dim2, contiguous);
    float** array2 = alloc_2d_float(dim3, dim2, contiguous);
    float** result = alloc_2d_float(dim1, dim3, contiguous);

    initialize(array1, dim1, dim2);
    initialize(array2, dim3, dim2);

    for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
        for(k=0; k<dim3; k++){
            temp = 0;
            for(j=0; j<dim2; j++)
                temp += array1[i][j] * array2[k][j];
            result[i][k] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. Something like `float **` is not a 2D array, nor does it point to one. Use a 2D array. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf: what do you mean? I'm creating an array of arrays, am I not?

Comment: No, you are not! You create an array of (actually a pointer to) **pointers to `float`**. A very different data type. I'd recommend you learn about multidimensional arrays. What you use is far from this and **probably** your problem.

Comment: float ** is a pointer to an array of pointers. This is not the same data type as a 2D array. A 2D array is simply a pointer which has much faster access times by using offsets. Technically a 2D array will "degrade" to this, but they are not at all similar.

Comment: What @Olaf means, is that you are using an array of *pointers* to line-arrays instead of a true 2D array. Such a true 2D array would be allocated with `float (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows*sizeof(*array));`. A true 2D array does not need a pointer array for indexing, and is always contiguous (and is thus allocated with a single `malloc()` call).

Comment: @jamesdlin `float* data = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(float));` is a contiguous block.  The code has two branches, `if(contiguous)` allocates a contiguous block and the other branch of that `if` uses one allocation per row. The question then compares the performance between these two branches.

Comment: @cmaster there are no true 2D arrays in C, if we're going to be pedantic about terminology . (Which is a pointless waste of time IMO, since the issue OP is asking about is still the same regardless of pedantic detail).  C only has 1-D arrays, the element type of which can be another 1-D array.

Comment: @MateoConLechuga: An array is not a pointer and it will not "degrade" per se. It just decays for **most** operators - yet not all..

Comment: @M.M: That is a matter of interpretation. In C an array of arrays **is** a 2D array and it generates the same access pattern/memory layout like 2D arrays in other languages. Anyway, it can change a lot for the question, because it has one less layer of indirection and the pointer-array will also consume cache.

Comment: Guys, I'm still confused. To me, both allocation methods in my code first create an array of pointers, then allocate a block of memory for each of those pointers. In the first case, those blocks are contiguous, in the second one they might not be. Perhaps I shouldn't call it an "array of arrays", but in this context, with dynamically allocated memory, is there any difference? 

Can someone please explain to me how the data structure suggested by cmaster - `float (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows*sizeof(*array));` - is different from either one of my methods? What is the resulting memory layout?

Comment: The resulting memory layout is exactly as with your contiguous method, *except for the fact that it does not need the pointer array for indexing*. With a true 2D array, `array[y][x]` translates into something along the lines of `array[y*cols + x]`, avoiding the pointer indirection.

Comment: Since no-one has come up with any explanation to your observed performance behavior yet, I think it would be helpful if you tried to boil your code down into a fully self contained example of post-able size. If you posted that, we could repeat your measurement and experiment with the code, probably getting closer to an explanation of this peculiar behavior. (It is indeed a very peculiar behavior that you observed, and I for one have no clue yet what might be the cause for it. I guess, the other guys looking at this question feel the same. So, please help us satisfy our curiosity ;-) )

Comment: @cmaster, ok, I think I'm starting to see it now. From your explanation, it appears that your method actually creates a "true 1D array", because it has to use global positioning to find any given element, and [x][y] indexing is just a syntactic sugar on top of that 1D array. I think I can achieve the same by allocating a normal 1D array, and then writing a function which would do the same index translation. Would it be not the same?

Comment: @cmaster Regarding the fully self contained example code - I did post the Github link - it's 115 lines, but most of it is formatting/measuring code. I could probably compress it down to maybe 50 lines, but I thought it's in optimal shape for experimenting as is. Do you still want me to post it here?

Comment: Ok, added the self contained code to the question.

Comment: I tested your code with `gcc` version 4.9.2 on my machine (compiling with `gcc -march=native -Ofast` as you suggested), but I cannot see any significant difference in runtime: Both, contiguous and non-contiguous allocations take 25 +/- 0.5 seconds.

Comment: This is very strange. I'm using gcc 4.9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I consistently see the difference in speed similar to what I posted. Moreover, I implemented your method of memory allocation, and it performs almost identically to my contiguous allocation method. Can you please post the output?

Comment: @cmaster, here's the "true 2D array" implementation: https://github.com/michaelklachko/NN/blob/master/test2d.c

Comment: Sure. For the non-contiguous run, I get: `Allocating memory: 0.4 seconds Initializing arrays: 1.6 seconds Dot product: 23.7 seconds`, while the contiguous run produced: `Allocating memory: 0.0 seconds Initializing arrays: 1.8 seconds Dot product: 23.1 seconds`. What kind of system are you using? Does it have several CPUs? Mine is a dual core on a single chip, so I guess, I should not see any NUMA effects; maybe those could be a part of the equation...

Comment: It's a 6 core i7-5930K 3.5GHz, AVX2 capable. I'll try a less capable machine later. I'm also wondering regarding your method, if I pass this "true 2D" array as a parameter to a function, do I lose the claimed benefits of less indirection as compared to my contiguous allocation method? This would explain why I don't see any speed difference between them.

Comment: If you pass a true 2D array as a parameter as you did, there is no speed penalty: It remains a contiguous array of arrays without any pointer indirection in between. As such, it is expected that there is no significant speed difference between your contiguous approach and the true 2D array: the inner loop of your test program iterates over the contents of a single line anyway, so the pointer lookup overhead is negligible.

Comment: I rebooted the server, and the issue disappeared! All three methods run at about the same speed. I also tried with larger arrays, and large number of iterations. It would be great to know what caused that issue though, because this is the server I use for simulations running multiple days, so a slowdown factor of 10 would not be tolerable. 
Anyway, thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've run into ability or disability of your compiler to run some vectorisation of your code.
I've tried to repeat  your experiment with no succeed -

mick@mick-laptop:~/Загрузки$ ./a.out 100 1 0

Multiplying (100000, 1000) and (100, 1000) arrays 1 times, noncontiguous 
  memory allocation.

Initializing arrays...

Multiplying arrays...

Execution Time:
  Allocating memory:    0.1 seconds
  Initializing arrays: 0.9 seconds
  Dot product:         44.8 seconds

mick@mick-laptop:~/Загрузки$ ./a.out 100 1 1

Multiplying (100000, 1000) and (100, 1000) arrays 1 times, contiguous
  memory allocation.

Initializing arrays...

Multiplying arrays...

Execution Time:
  Allocating memory:    0.0 seconds
  Initializing arrays: 1.0 seconds
  Dot product:         46.3 seconds

Comment: Yeah, as you can see from my last comment, this was a strange temporary glitch, which disappeared after reboot. So I guess we'll never know!